# Node JS Separate a function from a route

Tags: javascript, node.js

I created some code (a simple file uploader) that works well all on one file. I would like to start breaking up the code into several files. I would like to have a routes.js (to control the routes), imports.js (that contains my function) and my server. I am having problems calling my imports from the route. I am getting error imports is not a function. Thank you!!

Server.js -----------------------------------------------------------

```
var express = require('express');    
var app = express();  
var passport = require('passport');  
var ejs = require('ejs');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');   
var imports = require('./src/import.js');   
var port = process.env.PORT || 8080;   
app.use(express.static('public'));

require('./src/import')(imports);   
require('./app/routes.js')(app, imports);   

app.listen(port);   
console.log('The app is running on port ' + port)
```

routes.js-----------------------------------------------------------

```
module.exports = function (app, imports) {

    //home Page
    app.get('/', function (req, res) {
        res.render('index.ejs');
    });

    app.post('/import', imports(){});
};
```

import.js---------------------------------------------

```
var multer = require('multer');
var fs = require('fs');



module.exports = function (imports) {

    var imports = multer({ dest: 'C:/Users/ron/temp/' });
    var type = imports.single('file');

    imports( type, function (req, res) {//removed type


        var fileType = req.file.type;

        console.log('output' + req.file);
        console.log(fileType);

        var file = __dirname + "/" + req.file.name;
        fs.readFile(req.file.path, function (err, data) {
            fs.writeFile(file, data, function (err) {

                if (err) {
                    console.log(err);
                } else {

                    var fileName = req.file.originalname;

                    response = {
                        message: 'File uploaded successfully',
                        fileinfo: req.file,
                        filename: fileName
                    };
                }
                console.log(response);
                res.end(JSON.stringify(response));

                var filePath = req.file.destination + req.file.originalname;

                fs.rename(req.file.destination + req.file.filename, req.file.destination + req.file.originalname, function (err) {
                    if (err) console.log('ERROR:' + err);
                    console.log('the path is...' + filePath);
                    console.log('the name is...' + fileName);

                });
            });
        });
    });
};
```

Single file solution..................................................

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var passport = require('passport');
var ejs = require('ejs');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var multer = require('multer');
var fs = require('fs');

var port = process.env.PORT || 8080;

var imports = multer({ dest: 'C:/Users/ron/temp/' });
var type = imports.single('file');
var urlencodedParser = bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false});

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(express.static('public'));


app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.render('index.ejs');
});

app.post('/import', type,  function (req, res) {//removed type


    var fileType = req.file.type;

    console.log('output' + req.file);
    console.log(fileType);

    var file = __dirname + "/" + req.file.name;
    fs.readFile(req.file.path, function (err, data) {
        fs.writeFile(file, data, function (err) {

            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
            } else {

                var fileName = req.file.originalname;

                response = {
                    message: 'File uploaded successfully',
                    fileinfo: req.file,
                    filename: fileName
                };
            }
            console.log(response);
            res.end(JSON.stringify(response));

            var filePath = req.file.destination + req.file.originalname;

            fs.rename(req.file.destination + req.file.filename, req.file.destination + req.file.originalname, function (err) {
                if (err) console.log('ERROR:' + err);
                console.log('the path is...' + filePath);
                console.log('the name is...' + fileName);

            });
        });
    });
});

app.listen(port);
console.log('The app is running on port ' + port)
```

Comment: You really getting yourself confused on how to break up a file,.. `module.exports = function (imports) {  var imports = ...` this just doesn't make any sense for a start.

Comment: I was trying to follow an example from a Udemy course. Can you help me to do this a better way? Or direct me to a resource.

Comment: Do you have your source before you tried breaking into separate files?

Comment: you are making your code much more complex. You can much simplify it.

Comment: By separating it? If you are referring to the multiple outputs, that is there to help me understand the code. I'm new.

Comment: Have you tried below code is that works?

Comment: I am still having problems with calling the functions. I know how to export and import. I can't get the syntax to make code from one module run in another module. If I were to do this in java I would simply class.function(), and that function would do it's work. How do you do this in Node JS?

Comment: Let me upload sample code

Answer (score 0):

Note that every function you include in your router must have reqest and response object as a parameter.

Change your function as :

```
function imports (req,res){
//your code
}
module.exports ={
 imports:imports 
}
```

And now import this function in router file.